# Strange behavior: memcpy faster 1x when src is not set value

Tags: c++, memcpy

GCC version: `gcc 4.8.5`

copt: -std=c++11 -O3

```
SIZE = 50 * 1024 * 1024
```

The first piece of code:

```
int main() {
  char* src = new char[SIZE];
  char* dst = new char[SIZE];

  memset(dst, 'a', SIZE);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    size_t start = now();
    memcpy(dst, src, SIZE);
    cout << "timer:" << now() - start << "ms" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
timer:5ms

timer:4ms

timer:5ms

timer:5ms

timer:4ms
```

The second piece of code:

```
int main() {
  char* src = new char[SIZE];
  char* dst = new char[SIZE];

  memset(src, 'a', SIZE);
  memset(dst, 'a', SIZE);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    size_t start = now();
    memcpy(dst, src, SIZE);
    cout << "timer:" << now() - start << "ms" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
timer:9ms

timer:8ms

timer:8ms

timer:8ms

timer:8ms
```

The third piece of code:

```
int main() {
  char* src = new char[SIZE];
  char* dst = new char[SIZE];

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    size_t start = now();
    memcpy(dst, src, SIZE);
    cout << "timer:" << now() - start << "ms" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
timer:22ms

timer:4ms

timer:5ms

timer:5ms

timer:5ms
```

Summary:

1. Compare first and third case: first round of 3rd case slow is because of minor page fault.

Questions:

1. Why in the 1st case, memcpy src wouldn't trigger any minor page fault?
2. Why in the 2nd case, 1x slower than 1st case. Any optimization in OS?

Comment: your question don't make sense, is this a bad homework ? why in the case 3 there are not 10 lines output ? why do you suppose there are a "first minor page fault" in the case 3 ? and what does "1x slower than 1st case", mean's ?

Comment: Is your program the highest priority? What if your program was interrupted in between the start  and memcpy by the OS? How do you know it was a page fault? Why do you expect the other test to suffer the same?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox, clearly compare 1st and 3rd case, memset in 1st would did minor page fault for all dst's pages.  The test could be reproduced, so it's impossible because of interruption of OS.

Answer (score 2):

Memcpy is bounded by external memory throughput; it looks like the OS is able to allocate memory virtually into the page tables and performing [Copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write). This would explain both phenomena: there would be only one reserved block of physical memory for unmodified **`src`**, which would be located in the fastest cache in cases 2 and 3. In case one all memory access would go up and down to external memory. The 5x speed penalty in run 1 of case 2 is due to the virtually allocated **`src`** being copied on write to unique physical pages.

Timing the initial `memset`s N times in a row should confirm the hypothesis.

> The copy-on-write technique can be extended to support efficient memory allocation by having a page of physical memory filled with zeros. When the memory is allocated, all the pages returned refer to the page of zeros and are all marked copy-on-write. This way, physical memory is not allocated for the process until data is written, allowing processes to reserve more virtual memory than physical memory and use memory sparsely, at the risk of running out of virtual address space.

Comment: Thanks Aki, let me check the code in linux kernel, and confirm what you mentioned.

Comment: @TongxuanLiu I think it is `ZERO_PAGE` (single page filled with zeroes, with `VM_SHARED` flag up), as comment in `arch/*/include/asm/pgtable.h` suggests.